# Help identify this instrument

Tags: instruments

Is there anyone out there who knows the instrument that was used to record this sound? (the dutch train station sound)

My guess is some sort of bell mechanism, but i can't quite say.

Comment: Knowing how long the sound has been in use might help. It's a 'synth' but which one is not an easy guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is the 'Bell' voice recorded from a polyphonic synthesizer or electronic keyboard. (The way the tones sustain do not support a natural bell sound hypothesis.) I have encountered this patch on Yamaha keyboards and on Korg keys as well.

Comment: Old enough to be analog, new enough to have velocity sensitivity. Can't really say much more. Could be a DX7 at a push, but I'd guess nothing newer than that. hard to tell whether it's ring mod or FM.

Answer (score 0):

The first two sounds are definitely made by the same thing, possibly a bell. The third could be a synthesiser or piano, or even electric organ.